# print text that's between two specific other letters or characters, I don't know if urllib should be used

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
  <li><a href="/alumni/">Alumni &amp; Friends</a></li>
```

How can I print only '/alumni' and "Alumni & Friends" from the above HTML code?

Comment: have you considered [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing `html`?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
html_doc = """<li><a href="/alumni/">Alumni &amp; Friends</a></li>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    # or if you want exactly '/alumni' use
    # print(link.get('href')[:-1])
    print(link.text)
```

output:

```
/alumni/
Alumni & Friends
```

You can install [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or see [Installing Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) for more installation options.

Comment: It doesn't extract the text for some url it prints nothing. for example youtube.com

Comment: did you use `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(YOUR_URL).content, "html.parser")`? I can update the answer with the full code to parse example `youtube.com` if you want

Answer (score 1):

use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

"Since 2004, it's been saving programmers hours or days of work on quick-turnaround screen scraping projects."

Comment: How do i do that?